# How to make "seen" hash with python dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

In Perl one can do this:

```
my %seen;

foreach my $dir ( split /:/, $input ) {
        $seen{$dir}++;
}
```

This is a way to remove duplicates by keeping track of what has been "seen".  In python you cannot do:

```
seen = {}

for x in ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one']:
    seen[x] += 1
```

The above python results in `KeyError: 'one'`.

What is python-y way of making a 'seen' hash?

Comment: Look into collections.Counter

Comment: You're doing two different things in both examples: the Perl code is assigning 1 if seen whereas the python code is incrementing.  Your python code would work like the perl if you remove the add operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for getting this behavior. The catch is that you need to specify the datatype for defaultdict to work for even those keys which don't have a value:

```
In [29]: from collections import defaultdict

In [30]: seen = defaultdict(int)

In [31]: for x in ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one']:
    ...:     seen[x] += 1

In [32]: seen
Out[32]: defaultdict(int, {'one': 2, 'three': 1, 'two': 1})
```

You can use a Counter as well:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> seen = Counter()
>>> for x in ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one']: seen[x] += 1
... 
>>> seen
Counter({'one': 2, 'three': 1, 'two': 1})
```

If all you need are uniques, just do a set operation: `set(['one', 'two', 'three', 'one'])`

Comment: How is adding new keys on the fly easier with `defaultdict`? If you did the same thing with `Counter` it would work the same way. It would also be a bit simpler (no need to specify a function that returns `0`, or to know that `int` with no arguments does that), and more efficient, and clearer as to its purpose.

Comment: @abarnert My bad.. I seem to have mistakenly remembered that Counter dict did not support missing keys (the docs are silent that it does).. Have corrected the answer..

Answer (score 1):

If you unroll `seen[x] += 1` into `seen[x] = seen[x] + 1`, the problem with your code is obvious: you're trying to access `seen[x]` before you've assigned to it. Instead, you need to check if the key exists first:

```
seen = {}

for x in ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one']:
    if x in seen:
        seen[x] += 1  # we've seen it before, so increment
    else:
        seen[x] = 1  # first time seeing x
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
>>> seen=set(['one', 'two', 'three', 'one'])
>>> seen
{'one', 'two', 'three'}
```