# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str (Python)

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I am writing a program that reads an unspecified number of integers and finds the ones that have the most occurrences. For example, if you enter 2 3 40 3 5 4 –3 3 3 2 0, the number 3 occurs most often. Enter all numbers in one line. If not one but several numbers have the most occurrences, all of them should be reported. For example, since 9 and 3 appear twice in the list 9 30 3 9 3 2 4, both occurrences should be reported.

```
def main():
    numbers= input("Enter the numbers: ").strip().split()

    dict_numbers = []

    for number in numbers:
        if number in dict_numbers:
            dict_numbers[number] += 1
        else:
            dict_numbers[number] = 1

    most_occurrence = max(dict_numbers.values())

    print("Most Occurrence:",end=" ")

    for number, occurrence in dict_numbers.items():
        if(most_occurrence == occurrence):
            print(number, end=" ")
main()
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Enter the numbers: 1 2 4 6 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eriksaini/Desktop/Python/M09/Assignments/countLetters.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/eriksaini/Desktop/Python/M09/Assignments/countLetters.py", line 10, in main
    dict_numbers[number] = 1
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
>>>
```

Comment: `[]` creates an empty list, `{}` creates an empty dictionary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make "seen" hash with python dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638617/how-to-make-seen-hash-with-python-dict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dict_numbers = []` is a list. Use `dict_numbers = {}`

Answer (score 2):

You have used `[]` which indicates a list

if you are defining a dictionary you have to use `{}`

so this will be your final code :

```
def main():
    numbers= input("Enter the numbers: ").strip().split()

    dict_numbers = {}

    for number in numbers:
        if number in dict_numbers:
            dict_numbers[number] += 1
        else:
            dict_numbers[number] = 1

    most_occurrence = max(dict_numbers.values())

    print("Most Occurrence:",end=" ")

    for number, occurrence in dict_numbers.items():
        if(most_occurrence == occurrence):
            print(number, end=" ")
main()
```